# <li> not moving bullets with padding

Tags: html, css, list, padding

I'm trying to move the bullet points so they're inside my box wrap. They will not move. I'm also trying to have have an unordered list inside a ordered list as a sub-list.

**HTML**

```
<div class="box-wrap">
     <h2>Regler</h2>

    <p>
        <ul>
            <li>List Item
                <ol>
                    <li>Text Here</li>
                    <li>Text Here</li>
                    <li>Text Here</li>
                </ol>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </p>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.box-wrap {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    margin: 20px 0 0 0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 4px 4px 16px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    -moz-box-shadow: 4px 4px 16px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    box-shadow: 4px 4px 16px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
.box-wrap p {
    font-family:'Open Sans', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    padding: 5px 30px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: left;
    width: 640px;
    height: auto;
    background: #ffffff;
    color: #717171;
}
.box-wrap li {
    font-family:'Open Sans', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    padding: 5px 30px;
    width: 640px;
    height: auto;
    background: #ffffff;
    color: #717171;
    list-style-type: circle;
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Isn't that we just need to set `list-style:none` to remove the bullets? Or you want something different?

Comment: You didn't close your `<ol>` tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Aj2t6/3/)

You need to close your `ol` and add a closing `</li>`, to move the bullet positions you can also use `list-style-position:inside`

Also, you currently have your `ul` and `ol` the wrong way around according to your requirements, and are overrideing the default `li` numbering by giving all your `li` `list-style-type: circle;`. Change your CSS per:

```
.box-wrap {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    margin: 20px 0 0 0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 4px 4px 16px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    -moz-box-shadow: 4px 4px 16px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    box-shadow: 4px 4px 16px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
ul, ol {
    list-style-position:inside;
}
.box-wrap p {
    font-family:'Open Sans', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    padding: 5px 30px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: left;
    width: 640px;
    height: auto;
    background: #ffffff;
    color: #717171;
}
.box-wrap li {
    font-family:'Open Sans', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    padding: 5px 30px;
    width: 640px;
    height: auto;
    background: #ffffff;
    color: #717171;
}
.box-wrap ul li {
    list-style-type: circle;
}
```

Comment: I forgot to add that when I removed content for easier trouble shooting.

Comment: Yes, How do I make the <ol> have numbers instead of bullet points?

Comment: You have `list-style-type: circle;` set for all `li` items, you can make it only affect the `ul` (so the `ol` reverts to numbers) by changing your CSS selectors- I'll update my answer

Comment: Thank you, best answer. You can see the result here http://hjortefjellet.com/ttt1motd.html

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need? http://jqversion.com/#!/Xx29MFo

Pay attention to your HTML and CSS as there are some unneeded tags/properties.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get rid of the bullet points you need to add your css like:

`ul {list-style:none;}`

and if you want to have list inside another you can write like that 
For instance there is one list inside another

```
<ul class="parent">
  <li>Parent-1</li>
  <li>Parent-2</li>
  <li>Parent3
    <ul class="child">
     <li>Child3</li>
     <li>Child3</li>
     <li>Child3</li>
   </ul>
 </li>
</ul>
```

And then you can apply your css to your code like for instance I want to delete bullets of inside
list.

enter code here

`.parent .child li {list-style:none;}`

I hope this will work for you.

Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/E5eW6/14/

1. Removed the width on the li and p, put it on the box-wrap container.
   Otherwise they are going out of the box. Width should be set on the container.
2. Removed the default margins on ul,...
3. Fixed the style wrongly applied to ol list-items.
4. height auto has no effect whatsoever thus removed it
5. Added padding on the main container

   ```
    /* apply a natural box layout model to all elements */
   *, *:before, *:after {
     -moz-box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box;
    }
   .box-wrap {
       margin: 20px 0 0 0;
       padding: 20px;
       -webkit-box-shadow: 4px 4px 16px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
       -moz-box-shadow: 4px 4px 16px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
       box-shadow: 4px 4px 16px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
       max-width: 640px;
       font-family:'Open Sans', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
       color: #717171;
   }
   .box-wrap h2 {margin:0;padding:0;font-size: 18px;}
   .box-wrap ul,  .box-wrap ol {margin:0.8em 0 0 0;padding:0;}
   .box-wrap ul ol {margin-left:0.5em;}
   .box-wrap ul, .box-wrap ol {
       font-size: 14px;
   }

   .box-wrap ul > li {
       list-style-type: circle;
   }
   .box-wrap ol > li {
       list-style-type: decimal;
   }
   .box-wrap li {
       background: #ffffff;
       color: #717171;
       list-style-position: inside;
   }
   ```